# Assistant Professor Tenure Track Interviews

Tags: job-search, assistant-professor

I applied for Tenure Track Assistant Professor position in December at an R1 University in the US. I did a zoom interview on Feb 8. I am coming from the K-12 sector and this is my first faculty interview process. I had a question. I know the faculty are extremely busy and do not want to bother. My references were called last week and I want to know if it is appropriate to email the committee chair and ask if/when notifications for on-site visits or thanks for applying but we are moving in another direction would be going out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to ask? What will you do differently based on the answer?

Comment: I guess to start research for on-site visit versus looking for another position

Comment: You should always keep looking for additional positions until you have accepted an offer and are no longer looking for a job.

Comment: That is helpful. I appreciate your answers

Comment: I think our canonical question for these situations covers things here. If you're not successful don't expect to hear back, even after a Zoom interview. I certainly haven't this cycle, Departments are canonically lazy, have no incentive to give you notice, and will usually make all sorts of internal excuses to rationalize why they're not sending rejections in a timely way.

Comment: Most people who are applying for assistant professor positions are applying to dozens if not hundreds.  You should not put too much stock in any single position.  You definitely should not be applying to just one position at a time.